# What is the first thing that Quran commands?

Tags: quran

In Baha'i faith, in the [Kitab-i-Aqdas Paragraph 1](https://kitab-i-aqdas.org/p/%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B3_%DB%B1) it's said that the first command, or [Fard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fard) is to know the prophet of God (not even prophets, it's not plural).

I research about religions, and I can't accept that a religion that claims to be monotheistic in nature, commands you to know its prophet, rather than it's God, as the first command.

From reading Quran, I know that in many places it talks about submission to Allah, and worshiping Allah. But I don't know a verse that explicitly commands it as the first step.

Is there a trace in the Quran of the first command that Muslims need to obey? The first step that Muslims need to walk?

Comment: You should define what you mean by "first command". The qur'an contains a huge amount of commands! First according which order? Revelation this might be the only thing that could be answered to a certain extent?... Your question is rather unclear. Scholars rather consider a certain knowledge of the aqeedah as the first command for any Muslim. Because without knowing Allah and His prophets one cannot even speak about this religion and its rulings.

Comment: @Medi1Saif, if you see the link of the book I sent, you see that it has specified VERY CLEARLY, that the first thing is to know your prophet. ان اول ما کتب الله علی العباد. I want to know if we have something equivalent in Quran or not.

Comment: Well maybe shahada can give a clue. You say "There is no god but Allah, and Muhammad is the messenger of Allah". So, you first accept that there's a single God, and then proclaim Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is His messenger.

Comment: @SpiderRico, but there is no trace of Shahada in Quran. I need Quranic reference.

Comment: When I'm reading this vague text I don't even conclude that it refers to a prophet. To me it is totally unclear what this text is referring to at all. As for it statements 6-9 about prayer etc. these clearly lack any backup in the qur'an in fact they even go against its teaching. As for obeying the prophet you may find evidences in the qur'an!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "first".
The first `command` of Quran revealed to prophet Muhammad (SAW) is 'Read' in surat [Al-Alaq](https://legacy.quran.com/96).

The first `command` to believers when reciting Quran is found in surat al-Baqarah Verse 2.21:

["O man Worship your Lord, who created you and those before you, that you may become righteous"](https://legacy.quran.com/2/21)

source: https://legacy.quran.com/

Answer (score 0):

Baha'i is a sect that has split off Islam. Their scriptures are based on Islam but not accepted by Islam.

The Quran begins

> In the name of God, the Gracious, the Merciful.
>
> Praise be to God, Lord of the Worlds.
>
> The Most Gracious, the Most Merciful.
>
> Master of the Day of Judgment.

It is God Allah Who comes first.

We cannot recognize God without the revelation made to the prophets. In the Quran, the Book (the Quran) is placed in second place:

2:2

> This is the Book in which there is no doubt, a guide for the righteous.

We further read a summary of the Commandments; the order of the commands may be the order seen in this verse:

2:177

> Righteousness does not consist of turning your faces towards the East
> and the West. But righteous is he who believes in God, and the Last
> Day, and the angels, and the Scripture, and the prophets. Who gives
> money, though dear, to near relatives, and orphans, and the needy, and
> the homeless, and the beggars, and for the freeing of slaves; those
> who perform the prayers, and pay the obligatory charity, and fulfill
> their promise when they promise, and patiently persevere in the face
> of persecution, hardship, and in the time of conflict. These are the
> sincere; these are the pious.

In all religions of God Allah comes first. This is also the first comandment revealed to Mose, confirmed as the first commandmend by Jesus.